# MinGW Always Changing Directories

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw

Just a nooby question, but I was wondering that every time I use g++ from MinGW on a Windows 8.1 command prompt, do I always have to change directories to compile it? This gets very tedious for me at least because I like to keep different assignments in folders, and cd'ing all of that address kind of gets me a little annoyed.

I've seen my professor on his Linux machine that he doesn't need to change directories and just compiles the program as he finishes writing the program.

Right now my Environment Variables are set to ...;C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH% Do I need to add anything more to this or do I have to move all my files into a certain destination? I've also tried Cygwin, but that keeps giving me errors and the other answers on this site are very confusing. In fact every answer on this site has been kind of hard to comprehend... is there a dictionary that I should be looking before I read one of the posts?

Sorry!

Comment: Change directories to where?  Where your c++ files are?

Comment: Please post some error messages that you're getting.

Comment: Right now my files sitting in a folder with multiple folders in them on my desktop.